# How to do modulo thing fast (less execution time)

Tags: c, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I was solving a question on a coding website and this website has a limit for execution time of code.  My code takes 1.01 sec but the limit is 1 sec.
I am unable to find any changes in my code that can decrease the execution time.  Here is the link for the question :-
https://www.codechef.com/AUG21C/problems/CHFINVNT

> Chef is trying to invent the light bulb that can run at room temperature without electricity. So he has \$N\$ gases numbered from \$0\$ to \$N−1\$ that he can use and he doesn't know which one of the \$N\$ gases will work but we do know it.
>
> Now Chef has worked on multiple search algorithms to optimize search.
> For this project, he uses a modulo-based search algorithm that he invented himself. So first he chooses an integer K and selects all indices \$i\$ in increasing order such that \$i \bmod K = 0\$ and test the gases on such indices, then all indices \$i\$ in increasing order such that \$i \bmod K = 1\$, and test the gases on such indices, and so on.
>
> Given \$N\$, the index of the gas \$p\$ that will work, and \$K\$, find after how much time will he be able to give Chefland a new invention assuming that testing 1 gas takes 1 day.
>
> For example, consider \$N=5\$, \$p=2\$ and \$K=3\$.
>
> - On the 1st day, Chef tests gas numbered \$0\$ because \$0 \bmod 3 = 0\$.
> - On the 2nd day, Chef tests gas numbered \$3\$ because \$3 \bmod 3=0\$.
> - On the 3rd day, Chef tests gas numbered \$1\$ because \$1 \bmod 3=1\$.
> - On the 4th day, Chef tests gas numbered \$4\$ because \$4 \bmod 3=1\$.
> - On the 5th day, Chef tests gas numbered \$2\$ because \$2 \bmod 3=2\$.
>
> So after 5 days, Chef will be able to give Chefland a new invention

How is my code slow (by .01 sec)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--){
      int n,p,k;
      int j,remain,r=0,day=0;
      scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&p,&k);
       
       for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        remain = j%k;
          if(remain==r){
            day++;
            if(j==p) break;
          }
          if(j==n-1){
            j=0;
            r++;
          }
       }
        printf("%d\n",day);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Codechef likely stopped executing your code after the 1 second mark, meaning your code didn't actually take 1.01 seconds. You'll need to try a different algorithm.

Comment: You are right but I think my algo works well , it uses only one for statement and three necessary if(s) statements, can you provide a hint or something for another algo?

Comment: WIth your current algorithm, you loop through all numbers. With the bound of the questions, your code takes around about 10^5 * 10^9 operations. On average, a computer can do 10^9 operations a second. You'll still need to do 10^5 operations to loop through the input, but to bring down the 10^9 part, you'll need some math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throwing everything directly into `main()` makes it harder to test the program.  Let's split into a unit-testable function and the challenge harness:

```
static int days(int n, int p, int k)
{
    int day = 0;
    int r = 0;
    for (int j = 0;  j < n;  ++j) {
        int remain = j % k;
        if (remain == r) {
            ++day;
            if (j == p) break;
        }
        if (j == n - 1) {
            j = 0;
            ++r;
        }
    }
    return day;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while (t--) {
        int n, p, k;
        if (scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &p, &k) != 3) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("%d\n", days(n, p, k));
    }
}
```

Whilst editing here, I added the missing check that `scanf()` successfully converted the expected values.

Now we can add unit tests.  Let's start with the example given in the question:

```
#ifdef TEST

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(days, question_example)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(days(5, 2, 3), 5);
}

#else

int main(void)
{
    ⋮
}

#endif
```

We should add more tests as and when we think of them.

---

Let's look at the algorithm.  We're looping `j` over ever integer, testing each one for divisibility by `k`.  That's an expensive way to loop over all multiples of `k`; it's much more efficient to increment `j` by `k` each time, and not need any division:

```
static int days(int n, int p, int k)
{
    int day = 0;
    int r = 0;
    for (int j = 0;  r < n;  j += k) {
        if (j >= n) {
            j = ++r;
        }
        ++day;
        if (j == p) break;
    }
    return day;
}
```

Or more clearly, iterating over the possible remainders:

```
static int days(int n, int p, int k)
{
    int day = 0;
    for (int r = 0;  r < n;  ++r) {
        for (int j = r;  j < n;  j += k) {
            ++day;
            if (j == p) { return day; };
        }
    }
    /* shouldn't happen */
    return day;
}
```

---

That algorithm is still slow, since we're still looping and counting each day individually.  We don't need to do that, since we should be able to *calculate* how many days it will take to reach `p`.

Let's look at the example again, and lay out the numbers as we'll visit them:

```
0 → 3 ⤶
1 → 4 ⤶
2
```

Or perhaps a larger example, (18, *p*, 4):

```
0 →  4 →  8 → 12 → 16 ⤶
1 →  5 →  9 → 13 → 17 ⤶
2 →  6 → 10 → 14 ⤶
3 →  7 → 11 → 15
```

We know that we will have to do `p%k` full runs over the `N` elements.  Each of those runs will contribute `N/k` or `N/k + 1` days to the total, depending on `N%k`.  The final, partial, run will contribute `p/k` days:

```
static int days(int n, int p, int k)
{
    int full_runs = p % k;
    int long_full_runs = n % k;
    if (long_full_runs > full_runs) {
        long_full_runs = full_runs;
    }

    return 1
        + full_runs * (n / k)
        + long_full_runs
        + p / k;
}
```

That satisfies all the tests, including the (18, *p*, 4) set I added:

```
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 0, 4), 1);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 4, 4), 2);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 16, 4), 5);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 1, 4), 6);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 17, 4), 10);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 2, 4), 11);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 14, 4), 14);
EXPECT_EQ(days(18, 3, 4), 15);
```

And now there's no loop, so this runs in constant time, i.e. it scales as O(1) rather than O(nk) as before.

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm is \$\mathcal{O}(nk)\$ but could be \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

It is \$\mathcal{O}(nk)\$ because you reset `j` `k` times with `j` bounded by `n`.  This makes it very much like having two `for` loops.  Consider something like

```
int day = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < k; r++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += k) {
        day++;

        if (j == p) {
            printf("%d\n", day);
            r = k - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `- 1` may not be necessary if `k` is not the maximum positive value for `int`.

That would actually be \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, because the outer loop runs `k` times and the inner loop is \$\mathcal{O}(n/k)\$.  In this case, using two loops can be faster than your single loop.

It's also possible that the intent is to do this in constant time:  \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$.  You should be able to calculate `day` from the remainders and quotients.  Something like

```
day = (p % k) * (n / k);
```

That may not be complicated enough.  Consider if it matters if \$p\bmod k \gt n \bmod k\$ and perhaps the result of `p / k`.  But I'm relatively sure that this is calculable in some way.  I.e. that there is some formula that will give `day` in terms of `n`, `p`, and `k`, which you know.  The following may provide insight

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", day, (p % k) * (n / k), (p / k), ((p % k) > (n % k)));
```

You would replace the original `printf` with that one and see what it gives.  Try various formulas until you find one that works.

Another option would be to try to replace the inner loop with a formula.  That would be \$\mathcal{O}(k)\$ time.

```
int day = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < k; r++) {
    if (r == p % k) {
        day += p / k;
        printf("%d\n", day);
        break;
    }

    day += n / k;
}
```

None of these are tested.  They are just things that come to mind as possibilities.  I am most confident about the first one returning the same results as your original algorithm.  But all of them should be faster for large `k` and `n`.